# "BusyBox initramfs" prompt while attempting to install from live CD on 2nd HDD

Tags: boot, cd, initramfs, busybox

I've created a partition in `ext3` on my second HDD to install Linux.

However, when I come to boot the CD, I get directed to a `BusyBox` prompt with no other choice than help.

Other topics I've read on the subject where bound to the idea Ubuntu has been already installed, and that the partition needs to be just indicated or else. But since I've no Ubuntu installed, neither have I any partition that Ubuntu should consider like that.

How can I go through that?

Long Version:

The first time i've run the live CD at boot, it run well until i decided to activate the integrity verification, then it started to load then i had the "busybox" prompt error.

I've reloaded a image, burnt it slowly, but then it occurs the same.

I'll be giving details about the hardware configuration soon.

Comment: This question seems to have been abandoned. There has not been further information or activity added to it for several months, and you have not logged in since shortly after it was first posted.  I am flagging this to be closed. If you think this issue is still affecting you, you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Comment: @MartinThornton: we have 5 close reasons:  1. duplicate 2.
off-topic 3. unclear what you're asking 4. too broad (=too many possible answers) 5. primarily opinion-based.  The above is none of those, so I'm **voting to keep it open** (sorry about that, but thank you for leaving a comment)  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby It's off-topic -> no longer reproducible. If you want to read more about my beefs with the new(ish) closing system and its lack of a useful obsolete reason take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns/185129#185129).

Comment: @Seth: Whew!  TL;DR, but in the future I'll try to keep a more open mind on closure...

Comment: Ping me about it in chat if you want @fabby and I can explain better :)